# Data structure for O(1) search 95% of times

Tags: data-structures, hash

It is required to design a data structure such that searching can be done in `O(1)` times in `95%` of cases and more than `O(1)` in `5%` of cases. What is the best data structure we can arrive at? Elements stored can be either `integer` or `string`.

PS: My approach is to use a hash table. I know it provides O(1) access most of the times. But how do I classify that as 95% and 5%. Also I am not able to come at a good enough hash function.

If only strings are there, I could use `hash*33+c`, but what about the possiblity of being an integer. Also what is the optimal table size I should use?

Comment: Do you care about the worst case, or average case?

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no collisions, hashtable access is O(1). So, you want such a hashtable that at most 5% of insertions result in a collision. Obviously, we want to assume a good, uniform hash function. So...

So let's assume you are inserting 100 elements, and to get 5% collision average, you want the collision probability to rise from 0% on the first insert to 10% on the last one. Thus, the hashtable should have 1000 slots.

If you want to have max 5% of collisions on *read*, then you need 2000 slots (since for all reads you will be at the final collision percentage from the last insert, so the total amount of data should be 5% of the hashtable size).

Then again, it's been a while, and I invite all to check my logic...

Answer (score 0):

If you increase hash table size as more elements get added, then the possibility that an access is not O(1) goes to zero (with proper hash function, of course).

In other words, all the access is O(1). Note, that we talk about O-notation here, which has a hidden constant factor inside.

There are integer hash functions as well, for example [here](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/integer.html). Or you can just use a general purpose hash function for this purpose (i.e., treat the integer as a byte array, and calculate a hash for that).

About optimal hash tables sizes: there is no optimal size in general sense. You need to specify the exact requirements about what you mean optimal. The usual wisdom is to keep load factor below 75%, this way most access will only need one comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about 95% O(1) in the *worst* case: If you use [cuckoo hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing), then searching is O(1) in 100% of the cases. In other words, lookup is constant in the worst case. However, often search using a regular hash table (e.g. with [separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining)) will be faster on *average*.

If you care about 95% O(1) in the *average* case: With e.g. separate chaining, I don't think there is a way to *guarantee* searching is O(1) in the worst case. You can only talk about the average case. Sure, you can use separate chaining, and a small enough load factor, and on *average* you will get one lookup in 95% of the cases. But this is not guaranteed to be so. You could have bad luck, and then only 90% of the searches are O(1). For 95% *average* case search in O(1), the load would need to be such that according to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) the probability of collision is 5%.